# filter a regular expression line in text in c

Tags: c, regex, filter, count, state-machine

I have to count with a c program the lines and the regex lines in a text, which comes from a standard input. I know, i can use a state machine for recognize the line, which is exactly perfect for the regex, but in this case, my regex is very complicated:

```
    ^[^#]-?(0x)?[0-9]*W6.+[A-Z]+.*mmese(A|b)
```

Is there an easier way to filter and count it? Or I have to scan char by char all of them?

(end of a line is indicated by '\n')

ps: Sorry for my English, if you can, please correct it!

Comment: use a regex library.

Comment: How do you differ between "a regular line" and "a regex line"? `This is actually plain text.` is a perfectly valid regular expression and `? Hm?` is not.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Can you explain it? or send a link

Answer (score 0):

POSIX has regular expressions, and `getline` for reading input, thus something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

static const char *pattern = "^[^#]-?(0x)?[0-9]*W6.+[A-Z]+.*mmese(A|b)";

int main(void) {
    regex_t regex;
    size_t nlines = 0, matched = 0, linesize = 0;
    char *line = 0;

    if (regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline(&line, &linesize, stdin) > 0) {
        if (regexec(&regex, line, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
            matched ++;
        }
        nlines ++;
    }
    free(line);
    regfree(&regex);
    fprintf(stderr, "Total lines %zd, matching lines %zd\n", nlines, matched);
    return 0;
}
```